# C# Equivalent of Java IdentityHashMap

Tags: c#, java, dictionary, hashmap

As far as i know, there is no direct equivalent in C#. My current idea is to use a Dictionary with a custom IEqualityComparer, that checks for reference equality.

However, this seems to lose the advantage gained by hashing. Is there a way to get an individual hashcode out of every different object? Or is this impossible and I should use some other approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx) which calls `object.GetHashCode()` non-virtually - this is the equivalent of `System.identityHashcode` in Java. I think that's what you're after. So your `IEqualityComparer` would just use that for hashing and `object.ReferenceEquals` for equality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946790/how-to-use-an-objects-identity-as-key-for-dictionaryk-v