# How to use an object's identity as key for Dictionary<K,V>

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to use an object as a key for a `Dictonary<object, ...>` in such a way that the Dictionary treats objects as equal only if they are identical?

For example, in the code below, I want Line 2 to return 11 instead of 12:

```
Dictionary<object, int> dict = new Dictionary<object, int>();
object a = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
object b = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

dict[a] = 11;
dict[b] = 12;

Console.WriteLine(a == b);  // Line 1. Returns False, because a and b are different objects.
Console.WriteLine(dict[a]); // Line 2. Returns 12
Console.WriteLine(dict[b]); // Line 3. Returns 12
```

The current Dictionary implementation uses `object.Equals()` and `object.GetHashCode()` on the keys; but I am looking for a different kind of dictionary that uses the object's **identity** as a key (instead of the object's value). Is there such a Dictionary in .NET or do I have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: "object identity" is not a term in .NET - in fact your language is reversed: `a` and `b` are different objects (with different memory-addresses) but with the same *value* - your description implies you do actually want to use the key's value, not their memory-address.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need to build your own dictionary - you need to build your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` which uses identity for both hashing and equality. I don't *think* such a thing exists in the framework, but it's easy enough to build due to [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx).

```
public sealed class IdentityEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : class
{
    public int GetHashCode(T value)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(value);
    }

    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        return left == right; // Reference identity comparison
    }
}
```

I've restricted `T` to be a reference type so that you'll end up with *objects* in the dictionary; if you used this for value types you could get some odd results. (I don't know offhand how that would work; I *suspect* it wouldn't.)

With that in place, the rest is easy. For example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> identityDictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, int>(new IdentityEqualityComparer<string>());
```

Comment: I recently built a similar construct although I used [object.ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) within the Equals method as I wanted to check for reference equality even if the `==` operator had been overloaded (which may then call an overridden Equals method for the object).

Comment: @JamesShuttler: Even if `==` is overloaded by the *actual* `T` at execution time, the constraint here doesn't force `T` to be something which is overloaded, so this *will* be reference equality. (Try it with string, for example...)

Answer (score 17):

Of course the other answers are entirely correct, but I wrote my own version to suit my needs:

```
/// <summary>
/// An equality comparer that compares objects for reference equality.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of objects to compare.</typeparam>
public sealed class ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : class
{
    #region Predefined
    private static readonly ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> instance
        = new ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the default instance of the
    /// <see cref="ReferenceEqualityComparer{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>A <see cref="ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>"/> instance.</value>
    public static ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public int GetHashCode(T value)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(value);
    }
}
```

Design rationale:

- The class is `sealed`.

  > If the class is not designed to be extended, I'm going to avoid all that expense by sealing it.
  > — [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx)
  >
  > I know many people (including myself) who believe that classes should indeed be sealed by default.
  > — [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252738/146622)
- There is an [`Instance` static read-only property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640088/146622) to expose a single instance of this class.
- It uses `Object.ReferenceEquals()` instead of `==` because `ReferenceEquals` is more explicit.
- It uses `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` because I don't want to use the possibly overridden `GetHashCode` of the object, which may not match the behavior of `ReferenceEquals`. This also avoids a null-check.
- It has documentation.

Comment: I usually find it more of a 'crime' to have a public class then a non-sealed class. Very few classes end up being part of the desired public API: and unless it needs to be public, keep it internal (to the project)!

Answer (score 6):

As of 5.0, [`ReferenceEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.referenceequalitycomparer?view=net-5.0) now ships with the runtime.

Comment: @MikeNakis Because of the [contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) of `IEqualityComparer<in T>`, `ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance` works for any type derived from `object`.

Comment: Whoops, you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Use your own equality comparer

```
public class ObjectIdentityEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public int GetHashCode(object o)
    {
        return o.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(object o1, object o2)
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

Note that `GetHashCode` can be overridden, but the crucial check is made with `Equals`.

---

This is an old answer dating from before .NET Core times. As @KyleMcClellan points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210874/8809900), a [ReferenceEqualityComparer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.referenceequalitycomparer) (namespace: `System.Collections.Generic`) has been added in .NET 5.0

You can get an instance through its static `Instance` property. By pressing F12 in VS you can inspect the source code. `Equals` calls `ReferenceEquals(x, y)` and `GetHashCode` calls `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj!)`.

Comment: I think you mean overridden, but even so, it would be better to use `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` for efficiency. (Any reason for using explicit implementation for half of it but not the other, by the way?)

Comment: I used Microsoft's implementation of `MS.Internal.ComponentModel.ReferenceEqualityComparer`. I also wonder why they mixed implicit/explicit implementation. I changed my code to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Dictionary` with `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx)