# Using object references as keys in a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

**THIS IS NOT A DUPE OF [THIS LINKED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-the-field-of-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key) QUESTION!!!!**

That question is about using the content of an object (in particular the value of a specific field of an object as a key). This question is about using they reference itself. Identical content of 2 objects would still be unique entries in this example which **IS NOT WHAT THE OTHER QUESTION IS ASKING!**

I agree with [kevin-krumwiede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953590/kevin-krumwiede) in the comments that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946825/128511) is the best way to make sure what I'm doing works in all situations.

I'm using objects as keys in a `Dictionary` in C#. I want to associate data with specific instances of those objects. Is this safe and supported or do I need to do more than just declare the object as the key?

Example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Program
    {
        public class Foo 
        {
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Dictionary<Foo, string> dict = new Dictionary<Foo, string>();

             Foo a = new Foo();
             Foo b = new Foo();
             Foo c = new Foo();
             dict.Add(a, "bla");
             dict.Add(b, "bloop");

             Console.WriteLine("a in dict: " + dict.ContainsKey(a));  // true
             Console.WriteLine("b in dict: " + dict.ContainsKey(b));  // true
             Console.WriteLine("c in dict: " + dict.ContainsKey(c));  // false
             Console.WriteLine("a's data: " + dict[a]);  // bla
             Console.WriteLine("b's data: " + dict[b]);  // bloop
        }
    }
```

Seems to work. Any gotchas I need to be a aware of? Perf issues with using references as the key?

Note: There was [this mis-labeled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-the-field-of-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key) that was titled "Using an object as a generic Dictionary key" but the question wasn't actually about using an Object as a key. It was about using the field of an object as a key. I fixed the title to make it clear this is a different question. I don't care what the data in the object is. I only care it's the same instance or not.

Comment: No, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-the-field-of-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key is about your question

Comment: Are you worried about the objects overriding `Equals` to non-reference equality? I’m pretty sure that’s the only gotcha.

Comment: you need to keep the object instance alive all the time (static), so that you can retrieve the value/ compare the key later on. I don't think there is any perf issue.

Comment: The object will be alive by the fact that it's in the Dictionary right?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, that's certainly related. Not sure it's a dupe. It shows that if Equals and/or GetHashCode exist on the given object then those will be used. It doesn't say whether or not using the reference itself as the key is safe/works/supported.

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer shows how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, Jon Skeet's answer shows me how to make an object that has an impl for Equals and/or GetHashCode to do what I want. It does **not** answer the question of whether or not what I'm doing above works, is safe, and is supported. I suppose I could look at it as that solution will continue to work reguardless of how `Foo` is modified in the future though ;)

Comment: @gman It tells you how to make a `Dictionary` that does what you want, that will treat its keys the way you want regardless of whether they override `Equals`.